# how to get number to number specified of file by int-ftp:outbound-gateway with `ls` and `gets` command??

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

thanks for attention, i used spring integration and spring batch , i have a ftp-server for processing my files, in ftp server more than 1000 files exists that i read with ftp-adapter , i want a way to read number to number files for example 10 to 10 read the file, how do it  ?
my code is:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                          session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                          request-channel="inbound"
                          command="ls"
                          command-options="-R"
                          expression="payload"
                          reply-channel="inputFileSplitter"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to limit the number of entries returned by the `ls` command; FTP does not support it.

You could add a filter, but the gateway will still fetch all the entries before filtering them.

You can use a pattern, though.

Note that `ls` only returns file metadata (or simply the file name); it does NOT retrieve the file itself.

Another way to limit the returned list size is to not use `-R` and do your own recursion into directories.

Comment: thanks @gary for response,because i  retrieved bellow exception `throws an org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying` when get or put many files(more than 100) on ftp server with ftp adapter

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace. Look at your server log too.